# Qt библиотека Qtitan::DockPanelManager - как при размещении панелей выставить им начальные размеры?

Tags: c++, qt

При размещении панелей в Qtitan::DockPanelManager хотелось бы установить первичные размеры
панелей и оставить возможность менять эти размеры пользователем. При использовании
setFixedWidth размеры применяются, но возможность изменять их размеры мышкой пропадает.

Answer (score 0):

метод Qtitan::DockPanelManager::insertDockPanel в одной из перегрузок имеет
параметр sizeHint (QSize), что позволяет задать начальные размеры и не отменяет
возможность пользователя впоследствии менять размер.